# Access to generic instance property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

How can I access to the `Id` property of the `instance`? I have the following code:

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(Book book)
{
    if (book.Id == default(int)) {
```

And I want to make it generic now:

```
public class TheRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public void InsertOrUpdate(T instance)
    {
        if (instance.Id == default(int))//How can I access Id here
        {
            context.Set<T>().Add(instance);
```

I searched for similar posts and I think I should write something like `instance.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue()` but I don't know how exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a hack like this. Define an interface with only one property of type `int` called `Id`:

```
interface IHaveId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then state that you entity implements the interface:

```
public class Book : IHaveId
```

Last state that the type used in your generic Repository class should implement this interface.

```
public class TheRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IHaveId
{
    public void InsertOrUpdate(T instance)
    {
        if (instance.Id == default(int))
        {
            context.Set<T>().Add(instance);
        }
    }
}
```

Doing so you avoid the use of reflection, which is very expensive in general terms. Furthermore, your code now is more clear.

Comment: I have already an interface named `IRepository`. and this is entity framework. And also I want to apply this to `TheRepository` not `Book`.

Comment: Ok, I don't see any issue with this. Do I have misunderstood something? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean I add the property to the existing `IRepository` interface or create a new interface?

Comment: @user5032790, Create a new interface and have the entities inherit from it.

Comment: I mean you create a new interface that should be implemented by the classes that represent your Entities, like Book. Basically the latter means that after each entity class name you would append this `: IHaveId`, provided that each entity has a property called `Id` and this is the PK of your entity. Then in the `where` clause you just have to add at the end this interface. Please read from the start my answer and if something is not clear let me know, in order to make it. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks. I just want to know can I use this `public class TheRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class` where the `Id` property has added to the `IRepository` interface instead of creating a new interface for that like your code ? `public class TheRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IHaveId`

Comment: @user5032790 Of course you can do. Bad this is not really a good idea. The reason why this is not a good idea is the fact that `IRepository<T>` should contains "things" related to a repository, like a method for retrieve an entity by id, or a method for updating an entity etc. Whereas the property `Id` is the primary key of an entity, a completely different thing, which is irrelevant with the behaviour that should imeplement a repository. There is a principle that is called Interface segregation principle, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle.

Comment: @user5032790 start reading about this principle from the above link and when you have time read about it more thoroughly here https://web.archive.org/web/20150905081110/http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/isp.pdf. By reading this staff you will underestand in depth, why this is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the compiler knows nothing of `T` except that it's a class. This means that it can never know that it has an `Id` property, because there's nothing stopping you from creating an instance of `TheRepository<string>` - which doesn't have an `Id` property, of course.

The code snippet you mention in your answer, using reflection, is *not* a good way to do it. What happens if, as I mentioned, you create a repository of strings? This code will necessarily fail, because string doesn't have the Id property.

What you need to do in this case is make sure that class `Book`, along with any other entities you need to persist in the repository, implement a base class that includes ID:

```
public abstract class DataObject
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class Book : DataObject
{}
```

Now, you can restrict your repository to classes that inherit `DataObject`:

```
public class TheRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : DataObject
```

Now, the compiler is assured that any instance of T, regardless of what T is, always inherits `DataObject`, and thus has an `Id` property.